# Phalcon Rest Api

Tags: rest, phalcon

I'm trying to create Rest Api on Phalcon. The main question is - how to use BaseController in different controllers (it would be very conveniently get translations or info for logined user or check if user is logined in Base controller).

When I do something like that

```
$posts = new Collection();
$posts->setHandler(new PostController());
$posts->setPrefix('/posts');
$posts->get('/show/{id}', 'show');
$app->mount($posts);

$index = new Collection();
$index->setHandler(new IndexController());
$index->setPrefix('/index');
$index->post('/someurl');
$index->mount($index);
```

PostController and IndexController extend the BaseController. But when I get url(for example) "/index/someurl", I see that BaseController works twiсe.

Is there some way to parse url before setHandler and make the Collection dependently on url and parameters? Or, maybe, there is another way to organize code. Thanks.

Comment: Is `$index->mount($index);` a typo? Shouldn't it be `$app->mount($index);` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$posts->setHandler('PostController', true);
$index->setHandler('IndexController', true);
```

Comment: thanks, but I find another way. I don`t know is it valid or not, but it works, and there no hundreds rows of routing  
 $app->get('/{from:[a-zA-Z\-]+}/{act:[a-zA-Z\-]+}', function ($from, $act) {
    $controllerName =  $from."Controller";
    $controller = new $controllerName;
    $controller->$act(); 
});

Comment: This is defintely not valid way :D

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hartjo/phalcon-restapi-rain

you can refer to this phalcon rest api all controller is extends from BaseController